# Google font with space in its name, what's the correct way of referring in HTML?

Tags: html, css, fonts

This is the font I copied from the link at the google font webpage. Other fonts (muli, oswald, lato) works fine but sawarabi mincho is not rendered when I try to use it, chrome seems to use my default font when I want to use sawarabi mincho.

I tried

```
p{
    font-family: Sawarabi_Mincho;
}
p{
    font-family: Sawarabi+Mincho;
}
p{
    font-family: Sawarabi Mincho;
}
p{
    font-family: "sawarabi+mincho";
}
```

but none of these seems to work.

What is the correct way of calling the font that has space in its name?

Comment: it depends on the font-face, so show us the font-face. Also you didn't try the *trivial* one `font-family: "Sawarabi Mincho"`

Comment: @TemaniAfif What is font face?

Comment: when you add a new font you are obliged to define it using font-face and there you have the name of the font

Answer (score 4):

[Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Sawarabi%20Mincho) tells you if you click on "+" at the font, then click on "1 Family selected" to show up the tool window:

> **Specify in CSS**
>
> Use the following CSS rules to specify these families:
>
> `font-family: 'Sawarabi Mincho', sans-serif;`
>
> For examples of how fonts can be added to webpages, see the [getting started guide](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started).

So this should work:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Sawarabi Mincho', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!-- head: -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sawarabi+Mincho" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- body: -->
<h1>A red flare silhouetted the jagged edge of a wing.</h1>
```

Comment: I tried that the font still doesn't load.

Comment: Well, this is standard CSS usage as defined in the specification and any basic tutorial.

Comment: @user3000482 Did you include the font itself using `<link>` or CSS `@import`?